# custom search textfield position datatables

Tags: php, jquery, datatable, datatables

I am working on a project that is almost done in my office, there are several pages that use plug-in datatable and use accordion, in this case the problem is that the searchbox I created is irregular. how to fix this?

[Datatables Display so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cesTn.png)

All processes are normal, but my production manager has asked to change the position of the searchbox to the right

here my Datatables code :

```js
$current_script = '
    $(".accordion-toggle").on("click", function () { 
        var table_key = $(this).data("index"); 
        var table_tbody = $("#asset-"+table_key+" tbody"); 
        console.log(table_tbody); 
        if(table_tbody[0].childElementCount == 0){ 
            var table_aset = $("#asset-"+table_key).dataTable({
                 "pagingType":"simple_numbers", 
                 "searching": true, 
                 "AutoWidth":true, 
                 "scrollY": "400px", 
                 "ajax":{"url":"'.site_url($this->current_page.'/get/?get=1&lokasi=').'"+table_key,
                 "type":"post"}
            });
            //table_aset.ajax.url("'.site_url($this->current_page.'/get/?get=1&lokasi=').'"+table_key).load();
            $.get("'.site_url($this->current_page.'/get/').'",{
                 get : 2,
                 lokasi : table_key
            },
            function(data){ 
                 $(".tot_perolehan-"+table_key).html(data.total_perolehan); 
            },"json"); 
        } 
    });
';
```

Comment: check datatable styles property based on datatable version -  https://datatables.net/examples/styling/ "It may be like - .dataTables_filter { float: right !important; }"

Comment: did you add some custom css? because filter box is by default on the right,